# How to test onKeyPress function call - React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library, onkeypress

How would I be able to test the functionality of my onkeypress functionality?

- current onkeypress function is inserted in  element.
- Trying to test how to test function onkeypress was called input box?
- How to test what it was it called with?
- jest, react-testing-library, and react

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Component -

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';

    function Search({ setWeather }) {
      const [city, setCity] = useState('');

      async function getWeather(e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.target.blur();
          console.log('in here');
          try {
            const key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
            const uri = `APIURIHERE`;
            const response = await fetch(uri);
            const responseJson = await response.json();
            setWeather(responseJson);
            setCity('');
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('api error', error);
          }
        }
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor='search-box'>
            <input
              data-testid='location-input'
              id='search-box'
              type='text'
              placeholder='search city'
              value={city}
              onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
              onKeyPress={(e) => getWeather(e)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default Search;
```

Test -

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
    import Search from '../Search';

    afterEach(cleanup);
    const mock = jest.fn();

    describe('<Search/>', () => {
      test('onkeypress - function runs', () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<Search setWeather={mock} />);
        const inputNode = getByTestId('location-input');
        fireEvent.change(inputNode, { target: { value: 'city_here' } });
        expect(inputNode.value).toBe('city_here');
        fireEvent.keyPress(inputNode, { key: 'Enter', keyCode: 13 });
        // how to test function onkeypress was called inputbox?
        // and how to test what it was it called with?
      });
    });
```

Comment: In order to avoid confusion, are you indicating that `fireEvent.keyPress` is not working or are you trying to figure out if `setWeather` was called?

Comment: "How to test what it was it called with?" you don't--this is an implementation detail, or if you're referring to the DOM event object, something your test provides as a mock. Instead, test the effect clicking the button has on the user interface. In this case, you would test that the weather was retrieved. But since this is never rendered in this component, it can't be tested. You'd probably want to test wherever component controls the `weather` state. As far as `city` goes, you can test that clicking the button clears it out.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/269#issuecomment-455854112), a `charCode` param needs to be included with the `keyPress` method call: `fireEvent.keyPress(inputNode, { key: 'Enter', charCode: 13 });`